# SignalR: System.ObjectDisposedException with timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm playing with signalR and I want to send every 2s a little message to my clients.
So I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), and it works good for chatting, now, I want to implement my timer.
Then, I made this (**ASP.NET .NET Core 3.1**):

```
public ChatHub()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("hello");
    var timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Elapsed += this.Timer1_Elapsed;
    timer1.Interval = 2000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private async void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("tick");
    await SendMessage("user", "hello");
}

public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}
```

But everytime, I get this error (in **this.Clients.Add...**):

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

And I don't understand why, I checked stackoverflow, tried some solutions, but i'm already stuck.

Thank for your help.

---

Sample: https://github.com/Naografix/SignalRProblem

**Stacktrace:**

```
Message = "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'HomeHub'."
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub.CheckDisposed()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub.get_Clients()
at ****.HomeHub.<Timer1_Elapsed>d__1.MoveNext() in *****.Api\Hubs\HomeHub.cs:line 32
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need timer in a Web application?

Comment: It's for my final project, refresh temperature every minutes from my raspberry and send it to my clients

Comment: The client was closed. You need to stop the timer when you close the client/s.

Comment: I connect my client, the hub was created (and timer too) and after 2s, it tried to send message but I have my execption. My client still here

Comment: What is the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @AloisKraus added in my original post

Comment: So your Hub is disposed. Any idea when this happens? This is not visible in the presented code.

Comment: @AloisKraus No... I just have this code ^^'

Comment: @AloisKraus I created a sample here: https://github.com/Naografix/SignalRProblem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see [here](https://medium.com/@tocalai/create-signalr-on-asp-net-core-df7ac8a9e4ee) this:

> Don't store state in a property on the hub class. Every hub method call is executed on a new hub instance.

So I decided to search how to create a service for my hub. And this is what [Medium](https://medium.com/@tocalai/create-signalr-on-asp-net-core-df7ac8a9e4ee) does.
(Download their solution because lot of things are missing in their tutorial)

**Creating a timer in my hub was a bad approach**.

Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your problem is create a worker to tick every 2 seconds like following:

On your `ConfigureServices`

```cs
services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

The worker class:

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await this.hub.Clients.All.SendAsync(broadcastMethodName, "Some message...");
        await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```